# Java program works on Windows but not Mac

Tags: java, command-line

I made a small program for a friend and when I run it on my Windows machine it works fine. However when I run it on his I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SupplierControl/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SupplierControl.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Not sure why it would work on one not the other

Thanks

Comment: You're missing libraries as the error message states.

Comment: Can you show us how you are running in Mac vs Windows? The error suggests that java thinks the jar file is the name of the class you want to run, rather than a container of class files as you would specify with -jar or on the classpath.

Comment: Is this program a jar file? Do you start it from console or via file explorer?

Comment: I have the dist folder in dropbox and then just double click it in windows

and then from the mac tried double click but as it did not work i did the terminal and from that got the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you're trying to run it with a command that looks like this:

```
java SupplierControl.jar
```

Note that what you pass to the `java` command must be a fully-qualified class name. What happens is that Java is going to look for a class named `jar` in the package `SupplierControl`. That's not what you meant.

If it's an executable JAR, then run it with:

```
java -jar SupplierControl.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the way that the command is being run.  Assuming that it is an "executable" JAR file, you should be running it as:

```
$ java -jar SupplierControl.jar
```

but you appear to have left out the `-jar` argument.

---

If you leave out the `-jar`, the `java` command will interpret `SupplierControl.jar` as a qualified classname; i.e. a class called "jar" in the package "SupplierControl".  Of course, it cannot find the corresponding ".class" file ... and you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it with the command

```
$ java -jar SupplierControl.jar
```

Then you are executing the jar and all should be well.